# C# Error: 'Class' is inaccessible due to protection level

Tags: c#

I Have this error: 'CLGDMFeed.Dal.DataManager' is inaccessible due to protection level.
And I have no Idea why i get this.

Tis is my class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CLGDMFeed.Bol;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;


namespace CLGDMFeed.Dal
{
    public static class DataManager
    {

        #region Methods
        public static void SerializeFeed(string sFileName, Feed feed)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open(sFileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter binform = new BinaryFormatter();
                    binform.Serialize(stream, feed);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        public static Feed DeSerializeFeed(string sFileName)
        {
            Feed feed;
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open(sFileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter binform = new BinaryFormatter();
                    feed = (Feed)binform.Deserialize(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                }
                return feed;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        public static void SerializeIListFeed(string sFileName, IList<Feed> list)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open(sFileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    bf.Serialize(stream, list);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        public static IList<Feed> DeSerializeIListFeed(string sFileName)
        {
            IList<Feed> list;
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open(sFileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    list = (IList<Feed>)bf.Deserialize(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                }
                return list;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }





                #endregion
    }
}
```

This is my form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CLGDMFeed.Dal;
using CLGDMFeed.Bol;


namespace ViewerGDMFeed
{
    public partial class Viewer : Form
    {
        //Lijst van object Deserializeren van een bestand zodat je ermee kan werken
        IList<Feed> ListFeeds = DataManager.DeSerializeIListFeed("C:\\Documents and Settings\\sam\\Bureaublad\\Listfeeds.lfds");

        public Viewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //De namen van de feeds toevoegen aan je combobox
            foreach (Feed feed in ListFeeds)
            {
                comboBox.Items.Add(feed.STitle);
            }

        }

        private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Overlopen welke feed uit je lijst overeenkomt met de gekozen feed uit combox
            foreach (Feed feed in ListFeeds)
            { 

                if (comboBox.SelectedText == feed.STitle)
                {
                    //De labels invullen met de juiste data
                    ViewerLabelTitle.Text = feed.STitle;
                    //...
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Sorry for all the code

Does anyone kno how to solve tis problem?
Thanks

---

I have rebuild the classliberary and the error is gone.

But I have a new error: Metadata file 'C:\Documents and Settings\sam\Bureaublad\Herexamen programmeren\WindowsFormsApplication1\CLGDMFeed\bin\Debug\CLGDMFeed.dll' could not be found

Comment: Do you get any other errors or warnings when you compile this code?

Comment: Did you update the class and then forget to copy it to the location where you're running it, by chance?

Comment: Grzenio, Yes I have an other error: 
'CLGDMFeed.Bol.FeedItem' does not implement interface member 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'

Paul, What do you mean by Update and Copy?

Comment: Please post the exception you're getting, and mark the line it occurs on. You have one problem described in the question, and another one in your comment. Which one is it?

Comment: so, the question must be closed, because have answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you have an invalid reference in your project

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem! There was a method missing. GetObjectData. Stil don't get where the metadata file problem came from. thanx a lot for your answers.
Greetings

Comment: Answering your own questions is encouraged. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: If you correct a question then it is no longer a 'question' and/or no longer illustrates the problem. To provide your own answer like this is correct

Answer (score 1):

The code looks OK, so you are probably not running the version of the file that you think you are. Check and Open from the Solution-Explorer.

Comment: This could be the problem, because I also added a new button to my WindowsForm, but when I run it, you don't see it.

I restarted Visual Studio, but I still have the same error and I still don't see the button.

Comment: Yes, rebuild the dal (assuming it's a different project).  Check that your reference is to the newly built version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the assembly with Dal namespace has been signed with a strong name key. Sometimes unsigned assemblies could cause issues like that.

Comment: commenting why -1 would be appreciated. I had a case that was solved by signing the target assembly. No other action was made.